# Convert a list of IEnumerable<foo> to List<string>

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to convert my List of Token to a List of string.

Here's my class Token:

```
internal class Token
{
    private TokenType Type { get; set; }
    private string Value { get; set; }
    private int Index { get; set; }

    public enum TokenType
    {
        Verb,
        Word,
        Adjective
    }

    public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenizer(string source)
    {
        var token = source.Split().ToList();
        return token;
    }
}
```

What I wanna do is split the source string into a List of string and then use that List to do other cool things for my parser...
When I add this line of code, it tells me "Cannot convert from a `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<Token>`. How can I convert it?

```
var token = source.Split().ToList();
```

Comment: What is source string? JSON? A ToString override? XML? etc etc

Comment: Your question body doesn't seem to match your title, either. It's really hard to understand what you're trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's the parameter for the Tokenizer, it's a string that's gonna be read with Console.ReadLine.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you want and what you expect to happen. It might be worth trying something yourself and coming back here if you have a specific problem with an [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry, I tried lots of things, I just want to be able to split the source into a List of strings, but it cannot convert from one type the the other, I edited the question!

Comment: The error message probably means exactly what it says - you have a list of strings and you're trying to pass it off as a list of tokens. What is "token" and how are you constructing it? Please show details of what you're doing in the Tokenizer method. Also, is the Tokenizer method supposed to be static?

Comment: I'm assuming the error occurs in the `Tokenizer` method, we need to see the code inside of that else we are just guessing

Comment: I have to agree with @TheLethalCoder - I'm guessing the OP forgot to convert a list of strings to a list of tokens somewhere, but it's impossible to know without knowing what "token" is and how it was built.

Comment: This is all there is to my code, Token is supposed to be a string in a List, that can have a type (verb, adjective, word)...

Comment: So you're telling me that you never wrote the `Token` class

Comment: No, I edited the question, maybe it's a little better, no i know I have to declare token, i just don't know how can i convert the said token to a List of string... I just don't know how to convert it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says.

```
public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenizer(string source)
```

returns type `IEnumerable<Token>`, but

```
var token = source.Split().ToList();
```

is of type `List<string>`. There's no conversion between `List<string>` and `List<Token>` (or, for that matter, between `string` and `Token`).

You need to do something like:

```
var token = source.Split().Select(item => new Token(item)).ToList();
```

You'll also need to write a constructor that takes type `string` and initializes the `Token` with it.

You might also consider making the `Tokenizer` method `static` so that you don't need to have an existing `Token` instance to use it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, than you so much... I'm bad at questions lol